# grep for patterns in a log file during the last hour

Tags: bash, grep

My bash version is
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

I am trying to search for patterns which may have got appended in a log file during the last hour.
I have gone through other solutions proposed on forums, but they didn't work for me.
Please assist.

This is what I tried and didn't work for me -

1. grep "^$(date -d '-1 hour' +'%H')" /space/log/server.log  | grep 'ERROR'
2. grep -E "^($(date -d '-1 hour' '+%H')|$(date '+%H')):[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" /space/log/server.log | grep 'ERROR'

My sample log file looks like this -

```
[9/2/20 3:09:56:166 CDT] 0000010c SystemErr R java.lang.NullPointerException 
[9/2/20 3:09:56:166 CDT] 0000010c SystemErr R at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:48) 
[9/2/20 3:09:56:166 CDT] 0000010c SystemErr R at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:69) 
[9/2/20 3:09:56:166 CDT] 0000010c SystemErr R at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:670) 
[9/2/20 3:09:56:166 CDT] 0000010c SystemErr R at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2124.invoke(Unknown Source) –
```

I want to search for patterns in the log file during the last hour and send email notifications. The script will be scheduled to run through cron every hour.

This sample file doesn't contain error, I will be searching for errors,exceptions in this file.
Basically want to search for patterns in this file on hourly basis and send mail

Please assist me in this. I am stuck.

Comment: What does a line looks in your log file. Give sample.

Comment: [9/2/20 3:09:56:166 CDT] 0000010c SystemErr     R java.lang.NullPointerException
[9/2/20 3:09:56:166 CDT] 0000010c SystemErr     R       at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:48)
[9/2/20 3:09:56:166 CDT] 0000010c SystemErr     R       at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:69)
[9/2/20 3:09:56:166 CDT] 0000010c SystemErr     R       at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:670)
[9/2/20 3:09:56:166 CDT] 0000010c SystemErr     R       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2124.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: I want to search for patterns in the log file during the last hour and send email notifications. The script will be scheduled to run through cron every hour.

Comment: @user431092 These lines (that you should really add in the question instead of a comment) don't have the hour at the beginning and don't contain "ERROR" at all, do they?

Comment: you are right, I have modified my question

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help so you can format your data more readably.

Comment: Thanks danielleontiev

Comment: @user431092 I still don't understand why you start your pattern with `^` (meaning you're looking at the start of the line, where you always have a `[`) and pipe the lines to `grep 'ERROR'` if there's no `ERROR` to be seen anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
d=`date +%m"/"%d"/"%y" "%H  -d "1 hour ago"|awk -F "/" 'OFS="/"{sub("0","",$1);sub("0","",$2);print }'`

awk -v d="$d" '$0 ~ d {print $0}' file
```

Tested and worked fine